# C++ macros and std::ostringstreams

Tags: c++, string, logging, macros, stringstream

I have a static C++ class `Logger` with a public method:

```
static std::ostringstream& Log(int sev);
```

as you can see the method evaluates as a ostringstream so I can log my stuff simply typing:

```
Logger::log(MY_SEVERITY) << "hello world";
```

Since the compiler evaluates first log(MY_SEVERITY) and then the entire expression I need a second method:

```
static FVResult_t Flush();
```

to actually write the content of the ostringstream to disk. Flush() has to be called just before any Log() call so any time I want to log some stuff I have to call the two methods in sequence:

```
Logger::log(MY_SEVERITY) << "hello world";
Logger::Flush();
```

So far so good.

Now my question is, I'd like to write a C++ macro which incorporates the two methods letting me to do something like this:

```
LOGMACRO(MY_SEVERITY) << "hello world";
```

I tried with:

```
#define LOGMACRO(lev) \
Logger::Log(lev) \
Logger::Flush();
```

however C++ compiler complains about the missing ostringstream, as I expected. How to pass such ostringstream to Logger::Log(lev) only in my macro?

Comment: Seems a better approach would be to write an iostream manipulator which calls `Logger::Flush` for you. Then you could just write `Logger::log(MY_SEVERITY) << "hello world" << flush_logger;`

Comment: Why, are macros in this *at all*? The very requirement of the insertion operator dictates anything the macro expresses must return an `ostream&` of some kind and yours does not. Unless you're logging line numbers and file positions (which I advise, btw), there is nothing here that shows evidence they are even needed? An inline that takes the severity and returns the proper `ostream&` should more than suffice. (and I concur with john's comment above.)

Comment: why not create your own `LogStream` class, and do all the necessary flushing in there ?

Comment: @John: mmm how can you ensure that flush_logger() will be called last? neither C99 nor C11 dictate evaluation order (e.g. left to right)

Comment: Flush_logger is not a function, it's a manipulator (in this case a function pointer). It will be called last, how else do you think std::flush or std::endl work?

Comment: @WhozCraig: because everyone logs using macros right ? So it must be the right thing to do ! The right answer being: normally, on top of everything, the macro also gathers file name, line number and function name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use following macro

```
#define LOGMACRO(lev, msg) \
Logger::Log(lev) << msg; \
Logger::Flush();
```

Use like

```
LOGMACRO(MY_SEVERITY, "hello world")
```

However, I think, that function, or manually usage of `std::endl`, or use your own manipulator will be better.

Function can be like this

```
inline void log(int severity, const std::string& msg)
{
   Logger::Log(severity) << msg;
   Logger::Flush();
}
```

and then

```
log(MY_SEVERITY, "Hello!");
```

Comment: Well, it's not quite better in that you can no longer *stream*! Logs of the form: `"folder #" << folderid << " could not be " << action` are quite common and a function taking a `std::string` is really ill-suited!

Comment: @MatthieuM. it's right. All is depends on for `what` you need logger.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the macro is being expanded before "Hello world" is streamed to your logger resulting in the following:

```
Logger::Log(MY_SEVERITY)
Logger::flush();
<< "hello world"
```

Which is not valid C++.

The best way is to use a macro such as:

```
#define LOG_ERROR( msg ) \
do { \
    std::ostringstream oss; \
    oss << __func__ << "() ERROR: " << msg; \
    Logger::Log( LEVEL_ERROR ) << oss.str(); \
    Logger::Flush(); \
} while(0)
```

This macro can be used as follows:

```
void foo()
{
    /// stuff that detects a error
    LOG_ERROR( "Parameter X has an invalid value " << std::hex << x 
               << " should be in the range " << y " - " z" );
}
```

This will output something along the lines of

```
foo() : Parameter X has an invalid value F7  should be in the range 0 - F0
```

This mechanism also means taht you do not need to worry about resetting stream output specifiers such as `std::hex` at teh call point to the macro `LOG_ERROR`;

Alternatively it might be worth investigating `boost::log`.

Comment: yeah, already tried boost::log, it's a great library however to me it seems a lil bit overkill to include boost::log just to write some log lines to a text file

Answer (score 0):

There's a far easier non-macro solution. Let `Logger::log` be a class, with a `Logger::log::log(int)` constructor. `Logger::log(MY_SEVERITY)` is now a temporary, which lives to the end of the `Logger::log(MY_SEVERITY) << "hello world";` statement.

Now define `Logger::log::~log` and let it call `Logger::Flush()`.